# How to save combobox items in database using the insert into query?

Tags: c#, database

I want to save account in login database using combobox.

When I try to save, I'm presented with the error: "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement". I tried to find the error in my INSERT INTO statement but i was unable to figure out whats wrong. This is the code I used to add items in combobox:

```
cmbAccountType2.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        string str = null;
        str = "User";
        cmbAccountType2.Items.Add(str);
        str = "Administrator";
        cmbAccountType2.Items.Add(str);
```

And this is the query I used to saved the account in my login database:

```
private void btnSaveAccount_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save item?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string q = "INSERT INTO LoginDB (userName, password, accountType) VALUES ('" + txtUserName1.Text.ToString() + "', '" + txtPassword1.Text.ToString() + "', , '" + cmbAccountType2.Text.ToString() + "')";
                doSomething(q);               
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Transaction cancelled.", "Information");
            textClear();
        }              
        loadData();
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using LINQ to EF or something? Direct queries in your code like this are a huge security risk.

Comment: What sql backend are you using?

Comment: You may want to execute the query yourself using SQL Management Studio or something. Basically put a break point on the code to make sure the values being returned are what you expect and then put those into a sql statement and execute it manually. The only other thing that I can think of is that you don't have a database specified... just the server

Comment: BRogers I am newbie in C# so I want to try it first using MS Access as the database. But I also want to use SQL Connection in the future. So if you can give a link where I can start studying using SQL Connection and also using the LINQ to EF that would be a great help. Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

You have one extra comma here

```
"INSERT INTO LoginDB (userName, password, accountType) VALUES ('" + txtUserName1.Text.ToString() + "', '" + txtPassword1.Text.ToString() + "'**, ,** '" + cmbAccountType2.Text.ToString() + "')";
```

that is the reason of error,but there are some other things you can make better in your code,

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO LoginDB (userName, password, accountType) VALUES(@name,@pw,@accType)",yourConnection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", txtUserName1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pw", txtPassword1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("accType", cmbAccountType2.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

- Use [parametirized](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) query
- Don't use redundant **ToString()** methods

Comment: Sorry I just misplaced the comma there but still I have the same error. Let me try the parametirized query first then I'll give you an update. Thanks.

Comment: I already used the parametirized query but still got the same error. :(

Comment: can you provide your full code? maybe picture or something like that?

Comment: I've finally found the problem. Its on the MS Access that I am using as a database.The word "password" in the INSERT INTO query was not recognized by the Access as a column but as a word. Anyways, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO LoginDB (userName, password, accountType) VALUES(@name,@pw,@accType)",yourConnection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtUserName1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", txtPassword1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accType", cmbAccountType2.SelectedItem);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I think the problem is the I way I used the Combobox. I tried it already without using Combobox and it works fine.

Comment: I've finally found the problem. Its on the MS Access that I am using as a database.The word "password" in the INSERT INTO query was not recognized by the Access as a column but as a word. Anyways, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtPassword1.Text.ToString() + "', , '" + cmbAccountType2.Text.ToString() +
```

I'm not absolutely sure, but since it's a syntax error, I'm assuming this is your error.

It's part of the line where you make the query string.

```
string q = "INSERT INTO LoginDB (userName, password, accountType) VALUES ('" + txtUserName1.Text.ToString() + "', '" + txtPassword1.Text.ToString() + "', , '" + cmbAccountType2.Text.ToString() + "')";
```

Comment: Sorry about that Andrew. No, I just misplaced it right there when I tried to rewrite the code to be more readable. But still I have the same error.